# get the object which property contains an array as the value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing some objects like this :

```
var lists = [{
  "id": 1,
  "status": 1,
  "inputs": [],
  "outputs": [
    ""
  ]
}, {
  "id": "",
  "status": 1,
  "inputs": [
    "test",
    ""
  ],
  "outputs": [
    ""
  ]
}, {
  "id": "",
  "status": 1,
  "inputs": [
    "",
    "test1"
  ],
  "outputs": [
    ""
  ]
}, {
  "id": "",
  "status": 1,
  "inputs": [
    "gfg",
    ""
  ],
  "outputs": [
    ""
  ]
}];
```

From this array I want to get all objects in which the `inputs` property contains at least one element.
How can I do this?

Comment: @albert i have tried it using filter() but i am not able to do that,as i have started js from last 2 days
    function filterByInputs(obj){
    obj.filter(function(value,array){
    var length = obj.inputs.length;
    console.log(length);
    if(length > 0){
    }
    return true;
  });
}
 i am getting the length of the inputs property , and based on that i chek if the length is greater than 0 , then i will show the array which are having at least one element, but dont know what to do when i chek for the array length

Comment: why it is down voted ??

Comment: You should improve your question's quality by adding some code you have done so far. Since SO is not a code writing service, the people would help you by improving your code and fix errors, but not by solving your task in the way of "I need to do something. How can I do this?"

Comment: @albert ok so can u just tell me how to achieve ??

Comment: @albert, please don't go changing variable names in the question. It breaks the code in answers that have already been posted and goes against the OP's intent.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
function getObjects(lists) {
  return lists.filter(function (el) {
    return el.inputs.length;
  });
}

var arr = getObjects(lists);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LLpghn44/)

Comment: Instead of `lists.inputs.length` you needed to check the element that you passed into the callback which was `value.inputs.length`.

Comment: the result is displaying but messy ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter the array and return only items which has length of inputs array greater than zero . It can be achieved for example like this

```
var x=lists.filter(function(x){return x.inputs.length>=1});
```

Now x is the array that containts only objcets whose input array isnt empty.

Comment: You need `>=1` - has at least one element, not more than one element.

Comment: @trolkura when i printing on console it shows undefined ?? why ?

Comment: Because it should be `lists` not `list`. It's a typo in the code.

Comment: no , its stated in question that array is called list , code works fine for me

Comment: I've changed it back as the edit went against the OP's intent.

Comment: It means that you named the variable as you wanted. Changing it goes against what you intended in the question as well as breaking any code that was posted in answers prior to the change.